# How can I get a huge Linear Programming Problem? Any public data set?

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming

I'm working on a Parallel Simplex Solver using C and nVidia CUDA for my Bachelor Degree in Computer Science.
I've already asked one of my teachers to bring me a super linear problem with thousands (maybe milions) of variables and/or constraints.

But....is there a sample problem that is big and public? Any book that contains a problem like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Netlib](http://netlib.org/lp) has a nice collection of large-scale LP problems. See [this](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/cute/netlib.html) as well.